# PDOException when Uploading Image

Tags: media

I'm getting a strange error when uploading an image to my site. On upload, I use the Custom EXIF Mappings module to insert various metadata values into fields. This has worked really well for all but just a few images where I receive the following error:

> PDOException: SQLSTATE[22007]: Invalid datetime format: 1292 Incorrect datetime value: 'ÿî' for column 'field_file_image_date_value' at row 1: INSERT INTO {field_data_field_file_image_date}

I'm really confused by this error, especially by the value `ÿî`. I checked/compared the metadata with other images in Bridge and can't seem to find any differences. Any thoughts on what might be causing this?

Comment: this is in a custom module?

Comment: I'm voting to close this as off topic because it's a bug in the Custom EXIF Mappings module, and should be reported to module's issue queue, not here.